# An RSS aggregator for Linux with database or API?

Tags: linux, database, api, xml, rss

I'm quite [impressed](https://askubuntu.com/q/1275876/847449) with `FeedReader` to the point that I don't want to switch, but I now see that there's no further development with it.  I expect it soon to be deprecated.

In any event, I'm looking for a similar aggregator which works with `feedly.com` and preferably a similar GUI to that of `FeedReader`, with perhaps a database or even API available.